# Is it possible to created a multi layer dynamic form in html using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, bootstrap-4

I found [this jQuery plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/dynamic-forms-fields.html) that seems perfect, but the documentation is not robust enough for my skill level. I am trying to create a form with two dynamic layers. Here is my current [prototype](https://lirohdesign.github.io/jquery-subdynamic-form/), and here is the [source code](https://github.com/lirohdesign/jquery-subdynamic-form/blob/master/index.html). My prototype initially works, but it breaks when you try to add fields in the nested form of the second item.

Comment: do you want to be genrate new textbox on Add more button????

Comment: Can try this on good https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/creation-removal-nested-form.html

Comment: I may try that other jquery plug-in again. I was having a hard time incorporating the add and delete buttons on the nested form.